# How to use this code working if i use web user control of asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, webusercontrol

How to use this code working if i use web user control of asp.net ?

```
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#sumit").click(function(){

    var vCheckedCBCount =  $("input:checkbox").filter(function(index){ 
    return $(this)[0].checked == true;
    }).length;
    if(vCheckedCBCount > 5)
    {
        alert('You cannot check more than 5 check box.');
        return false;
    } 
});
 </script >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: title tag should be in the head, not inside the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

First

```
  $("#sumit").click(function(){...}
```

Is looking for an HTML element with an id of 'sumit' (the # means ID in JQuery).

If you view the source of your page you'll see that Button1 when converted by ASP.Net into an HTML-side button won't have that ID as ASP.Net will generate a fairly unreadable unique clientside Id - something full of $ signs and underscores probably.

Jquery can find your button by its class using $('.myClass') - the '.' means 'class' just as '#' means 'ID' so just add the class `submit` to your ASP.Net `Button1`:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass='submit' />
```

Then modify your JavaScript call:
Firstly, ensure the eventhandlers are getting wired up when the document is ready by wrapping up your javascript inside the standard JQuery syntax to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Your Javascript goes in here.
});
```

So when re-worked it looks like this (I've moved a few things around and taken out your `<title>` element.)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submit").click(function () {

            /* this code is here for demo purposes only - 5arx*/
            var numchecked = 0;

            $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    //alert('checked');
                    numchecked++;
                }
            });

            if (numchecked > 5) {
                alert('You cannot check more than 5 check box.');
            }

            return false; //This will stop your ASP.Net button submitting the form via a Postback.
            /* Your orginal code.
            var vCheckedCBCount = $("input:checkbox").filter(function (index) {
            return $(this)[0].checked == true;
            }).length;

            if (vCheckedCBCount > 5) {
            alert('You cannot check more than 5 check box.');

            }
            */
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox10" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="submit" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps. For more useful JQuery stuff, have a look at www.visualjquery.com - its an interactive JQuery testing/learning tool.

Hth. Good luck  :-)

Answer (score -1):

`$("#sumit")` is looking for an element with ID="sumit", which neither of your elements have. Assuming you want to hook your button's click event, try `$("#Button1")`.

Comment: ya i have changed  ... my problem was that my whole coding and controls are on the webusercontrols ...when i drag that user control to webform.aspx then it will not work ...otherwise normally it works fine ... if i use all the controls and jquery function in webform.aspx page without using webusercontrol ..

Comment: #Button1 won't work as ASP.Net will generate a large and non-catchy ID for the control - do a View Source to see this.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean re: ClientID ...?

Comment: Pre ASP.NET 4.0 - <asp:Button ID="Button1", then in JavaScript - <%= Control.ClientID %>

Comment: ASP.NET 4.0 - <asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="Button1"

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: Apologies given the amount of 'newbieness' demonstrated by this post I made the assumption that s/he was using v.3.5

Its a fair point and remiss of me to make such a careless assumption without checking so please have a +1 by way of apology for the oversight  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, asker didn't give a lot of info. Also, a +1 to a comment doesn't do anything haha